# Calculate the average of a field in an embedded document array of a specific object id value

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am using a sample data set in MongoDB
I want to know the average exam score for class 149. There are multiple values in this dataset with class 149 so I need the average of just the "exam" scores for all values that have class_id=149. Scores is an array with multiple objects but I only care about type:"exam". How can this be achieved using aggregation or another method?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHZzC.png)

Comment: Share the data as snippet instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

first deconstruct `scores` array using `$unwind` then match documents with `class_id` and `score.type` then using `$group` get the average

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$scores"
  },
  {
    $match: { 
        'scores.type': 'exam', 
        class_id: 149 
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        class_id: '$class_id',
        score_type: '$scores.type'
      },
      "avg": { $avg: '$scores.score' }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these operators to calculate the average score of exam.

1. `$filter`: Filter the documents in the `score` array with "exam" type.
2. `$map`: Generate the array field with `score` from the result (1).
3. `$avg`: Average the result (2).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      class_id: 149
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      avg_exam_score: {
        $avg: {
          "$map": {
            "input": {
              $filter: {
                input: "$scores",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.type",
                    "exam"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "in": "$$this.score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0JkG8AbhyTW)